# ZFS 3 Disk Mirror Pool with 1 Disk Removed Occasionally

Tags: zfs, mirroring

I have a ZFS pool that contains 3 disks mirroring each other.  I would like to be able to take one of the disks and store it offline and offsite for a few months then re-introduce it to the pool, sync the data, take another drive offline and repeat.  This scheme will always leave 2 drives active in the ZFS pool.  Sending the data to another server is not an option.  I would like the data on the disk that will be taken offline to be available if I ever need to access that backup (say the server burns down or something catastrophic).  I would also like to still be able to monitor the health of the ZFS pool in case one of the 2 active drives starts to have issues.  ZFS dataset encryption will be used on all 3 drives.

1. What is the best method to accomplish this?  Would the ZFS "offline" command be sufficient to take one of the disks offline and then simply bring it back "online" at a later date to re-sync the data?  Would the data on the offlined disk be available using this method if I ever need to access it?
2. Would ZFS complain about the offlined disk using this method?  I basically want to be able to check on the health of the pool with the 1 disk removed in case any of the 2 remaining drives fail.
3. Any foreseeable issues if I use ZFS native encryption for the datasets in the pool using this schema?  I am thinking if the server burns down, would I have any issues decrypting the data on the remaining drive in the future?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why bother? Use snapshots and/or bookmarks + `zfs send` to do a proper backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the ZFS "offline" command be sufficient to take one of the disks offline and then simply bring it back "online" at a later date to re-sync the data?

Yes. Offline a disk before removing it, is the way you tell ZFS where the active data are. An off-lined disk re-plugged later will be updated with the new data from the pool.

> Would the data on the off-lined disk be available using this method if I ever need to access it?

Yes. Just import it on another ZFS system, but beware:

- As a lone disk from a mirror, it will be imported as a faulted pool, and if the disk is damaged, you will had corruption (or nothing)
- If you did not import in *read-only mode* you will break the «relation» with the source pool and get troubles if you put the disk in the source pool after writing on it somewhere else.

> Would ZFS complain about the off-lined disk using this method?

Yes. An offline disk put the pool in degraded status

> I basically want to be able to check on the health of the pool with the 1 disk removed in case any of the 2 remaining drives fail.

It depends what you expect by *«able to check»*, and note that «removed» is not the same as «offlined» in ZFS context.

IMHO, do not plan to move disk in a regular process if you expect data integrity. Disk are not meant to be moved frequently. This looks like a *«tape backup»* with ZFS disks instead of tapes…

Keep in mind that *storage* **is not** *backup*:

- Storage is hardware
- Backup is a process (using hardware, software, strategy, etc.)

A ZFS pool is just storage, do not plan to move disk with live data until you are in disaster recovery plan.